# scraping multiple URLs with bs4

Tags: python, url, beautifulsoup, match, google-patent-search

I am trying to compile patent files from the USPTO webpage with BeautifulSoup.

```py
df['link']
urls=df['link'].to_numpy()
urls
for i in urls:
    page = requests.get(i)
    ## storing the content of the page in a variable
    txt = page.text
    ## creating BeautifulSoup object
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')
    soup
```

however, it only prints one of the URLs, not all 5 links.  I NEED all 5 links scraped as text.

Any suggestions appreciated.  Cheers

LINKS I NEED TO **SCRAPE**#

```py
array(['http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&co1=AND&d=PTXT&s1=g06n.CPCL.&OS=CPCL/g06n&RS=CPCL/g06n',
       'http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r=2&f=G&l=50&co1=AND&d=PTXT&s1=g06n.CPCL.&OS=CPCL/g06n&RS=CPCL/g06n',
       'http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r=3&f=G&l=50&co1=AND&d=PTXT&s1=g06n.CPCL.&OS=CPCL/g06n&RS=CPCL/g06n',
       'http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r=4&f=G&l=50&co1=AND&d=PTXT&s1=g06n.CPCL.&OS=CPCL/g06n&RS=CPCL/g06n',
       'http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r=5&f=G&l=50&co1=AND&d=PTXT&s1=g06n.CPCL.&OS=CPCL/g06n&RS=CPCL/g06n'],
      dtype=object)
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Hi, I expect to compile all the text in the URL and convert it to a text file.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd


def Main(url):
    for item in range(1, 6):
        df = pd.read_html(url.format(item), attrs={
                          'width': '100%'}, skiprows=1, match=r"^\d{4}/\d+")[0]
        df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False, mode="a")


Main("http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r={}&f=G&l=50&co1=AND&d=PTXT&s1=g06n.CPCL.&OS=CPCL/g06n&RS=CPCL/g06n")
```

Output: [View Online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/0fdbd813697964c61a270e13176f4ebe/data.csv)

> ScreenShot:

[image]

> New Code per use-request in comments:

```py
import requests


def Main(url):
    for item in range(1, 6):
        with requests.Session() as req:
            r = req.get(url.format(item))
            with open("data.txt", 'a') as f:
                f.writelines(r.text)


Main("http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r={}&f=G&l=50&co1=AND&d=PTXT&s1=g06n.CPCL.&OS=CPCL/g06n&RS=CPCL/g06n")
```

Comment: Hi, I tried but didn't have the same outcome. But also, what I want is to compile the entire text in the URLs.

Comment: @patach what do you mean? edit your question with your expected output

Comment: I apologize If I framed it in a wrong way, I am new to coding. My question is, I have a bunch of patent links and I need to get all texts available at each URLs. Later I will apply sentiment analysis but before going that, I need the texts in each URLs. Thank you so much for your quick reply and kindness. have a nice weekend!

Comment: @patach which text?

Comment: texts available at each link. Like, once you click the link, the texts available at the per link. thanks.

Comment: @patach well, your first question was about `compile patent files` then you've switched for compile entire text. once you know what you want exactly. let us know.

Comment: As being apologized above and mentioned that maybe I framed in a wrong way, I think I already told it. Let me know if you have a clear answer to my question. Thank you for your kindness.